# 301 redirect of a group of related paths in Rails 3 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I want to set up a permanent redirect of every path that begins with `/articles` to the analogous path that begins with `/blog`.

I know how to redirect paths individually in the routes, e.g.

`match "/articles/" => redirect("/blog/")`

However, if I also want to redirect paths such as `/articles/:id` and `/articles/category/:id` etc., I'll need to have explicit redirects for those as well.

I'm hoping that there's a way to redirect all such paths, present and future, with one fell swoop.

I realize that I could do this relatively easily in the controller with a `before_filter`, but I believe this behavior belongs in the routes and I'm hoping to keep it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match '/articles(/*path)' => redirect { |params, req| "/blog/#{params[:path]}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

*The problem was catching the routes with parameters, now it should be solved*

Following the rails guides, the way to do it should be:

```
match "/articles(/:action(/:id(.:format)))" => redirect {|p, req| "/blog/#{req.subdomain}" }
```

Extracted from [Redirection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Neither of these options seems to work for me. The first one deals with `/articles` correctly, but doesn't match other paths beginning with `/articles`. The second one redirects `/articles` to `/blog/articles`, and also doesn't match other paths beginning with `/articles`

Comment: The problem was catching the routes with parameters, that now should be solved. Let me know if you have nested routes

Comment: No, it's loosing the path, I think because there is no subdomain, and so `req.subdomain` evaluates to the empty string (or nil?). The result is that `/articles/[anything or nothing]` redirects to `/users`. Thanks for investigating, though. You've opened up some new lines of inquiry for me. On the other hand, perhaps this is best done in nginx...

Comment: Welcome!! and sorry for not being able to help you! :D